# Navbar collapsed dropdown overlaps text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, breakpoints, dropdown

I am using bootstrap and changed the navbar breakpoint because we have a lot of items there. To reduce that i used a couple of dropdowns and they work perfectly in desktop and mobile, but tablets have an issue when opening the dropdown.
Between the new breakpoint (991px) and the default one (768px) the dropdown menu does not push the content below it like in mobile, but overlaps it like in desktop.

This is the css I use for changing the breakpoint, probably missing something there but no idea what :(

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-header {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
      float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
      display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
      border-top: 1px solid transparent;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
      top: 0;
      border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
      display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
      float: none!important;
      margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in{
      display:block !important;
  }
}
```

And here you have the jsfiddle to have a better look to my explanation.
[JsFiddle to the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/nato522/dxfu0hyh/11/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following css inside your styles:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

Here is the working snippet:

```css
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in{
    display:block !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">EN <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">ES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">EN</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

find updated here jsfiddle.net/dxfu0hyh/12/ Try applying styles for .drodown-menu class :hover :focus etc.,